# How to find the least frequent value in a column of dataframe in R

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe column with `userID` where there are duplicates. I was asked to find the `userID` that appear least frequent. What are the possible methods to achieve this. Only using `Base R` or `Dplyr` packages.

Something like this

```
userID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,4,4,4,4,3)
```

Expected Output would be 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If this is based on the lengths of same adjacent values

```
with(rle(userID), values[which.min(lengths)])
#[1] 3
```

Or if it is based on the full data values

```
names(which.min(table(userID)))
#[1] "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to get the min of mode:

```
# example dataframe
df <- data.frame(userID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,4,4,4,4,3))

# define Mode function
Mode <- function(x){
  a = table(x) # x is a column
  return(a[which.min(a)])
}

Mode(df$userID)

# Output:
3 #value
1 #count
```

Gives the value `3` and the count `1`